# What is this event handler doing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, dom-events

I've tried inspecting the DOM and so forth, and am not sure why '.tooltip' is appended to the handler. It doesn't effect anything if removed, and seemingly has no significant value:

```
    g.selectAll("circle")
        //
        //why is .tooltip appended here?
        //
        .on("mouseover.tooltip", function(d) {
        d3.select("text#" + d.line_id).remove();
        d3.select("#chart")
            .append("text")
            .text(d.late_percent + "%")
                .attr("x", time_scale(d.time) + 10)
                .attr("y", percent_scale(d.late_percent) - 10)
                .attr("id", d.line_id);
    });
```

Any clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a namespace

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

> "jQuery provides a concept called namespaced events: Simply add a
>   classname to your event when you declare it. You can then reference
>   that namespaced event both with unbind and trigger."

```
$('.class').bind('click.namespace', function(){}); 
$('.class').trigger('click.namespace');
$('.class').unbind('click.namespace');
```

Comment: This is correct, but note that the OP is *not* using jQuery - he's using D3, which provides similar event namespacing.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Jan ;) Solved!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as explained in [D3 documentation for selection.on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), it's just a way to register multiple listeners for the same event. For example, if you want to register two listeners for `mouseover` you need to use `.on("mouseover.foo",...` and `.on("mouseover.bar",...`.

Otherwise if you use just `.on("mouseover",..` twice you will replace the already registered listener for `mouseover` instead of adding a new one. The `tooltip` part has no special meaning it's just an identifier.